# SymPy simplify does not attempt factoring

Tags: sympy

Is there a workaround for SymPy's apparent inability to simplify sqrt(x**2+2*x+1)?

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x', real=True, positive=True)
simplify(sqrt(x**2))  # returns x
simplify(sqrt(x**2+2*x+1)) #fails to return x+1
```

Comment: I beleive it always simplify automaticly

Answer (score 0):

SymPy does not try to simplify everything on sight, there are too many issues (starting with performance) if it did that. See the article [Automatic Simplification](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Automatic-Simplification) in SymPy wiki.

If you want to factor an expression, you should tell SymPy to do that.

```
factor(sqrt(x**2+2*x+1))   # returns x+1
```

The formula `sqrt(x**2)` becomes `x` because `(x**a)**b` can be safely combined to `x**(a*b)` when the base is positive and exponents are real.  (Even then, "can" does not always mean "should be". Some amount of automatic simplification is present in SymPy, maybe too much.)

The key difference between the two is that `x**2` is a explicitly a power while `x**2 + 2*x + 1` is a sum.

Comment: I edited my question by adding "simplify" which also fails to factor. So I guess it's of a matter of simplify failing to attempt to factor than anything with the square root.

Comment: `simplify` does not consider `(x+1)**2` to be simpler than `x**2+2*x+1`; this exact example is considered in the [tutorial](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html). Granted, with the square root on top (and with x being positive) it probably should. Still, the typical answer is that simplification is not a well-defined concept like factorization; so to get predictable performance one should apply specific transformations like `factor`, `expand`, `logcombine`, etc.

Comment: Any suggestion for what one can do when the input is dictated by the user rather than the developer? In other words, my code doesn't know what kind of expression it's dealing with. (Also, simplify(x+1 - sqrt(x**2+2*x+1)) is not zero.)

Comment: You can raise an issue on [SymPy tracker](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues) about simplification like this. In general, it is inevitable that some of the user input will leave the user unsatisfied with the simplification they got from SymPy.